# Copy Queue results in seg fault

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault, queue

I have a function that i traced down to causing a seg fault, but i can't seem to find what i'm doing wrong. I'm trying to use print statements to find where the seg fault occurs, but apparently the function runs through with no problems THEN seg faults. Here is the function:

```
//note all of the cout statements are executed
template<class Type>
void linkedQueue<Type>::copyQueue(const linkedQueue<Type>& otherQueue)
{
    //if the queue is in use, delete its contents
    if(!isQueueEmpty())
        initializeQueue();
    if(otherQueue.isQueueEmpty()) {
        queueFront = NULL;
        queueRear = NULL;
        count = 0;
    } else {
        queueNodeType<Type> *current, *newNode, *last;
        current = otherQueue.queueFront;

        queueFront = new queueNodeType<Type>;
        queueFront->info = current->info;
        queueFront->link = NULL;

        last = queueFront;
        current = current->link;
        while(current != NULL) {
            newNode = new queueNodeType<Type>;

            newNode->info = current->info;
            newNode->link = NULL;
            queueRear = newNode;
            last->link = newNode;
            last = newNode;
            cout << current->info << endl;
            current = current->link;
        }
        cout << "here?\n";
        count = otherQueue.count;
    }
    cout << "ended\n";
}
```

this function is called in main with:

```
linkedQueue<int> queue4(queue3);
```

the seg fault happens directly after this line is called, what could i be doing wrong?

p.s. the copy constructor simply sets queueFront to NULL and calls the copy function.

Comment: Use a debugger. It will stop where the crash happens.

Comment: Step thru it in the debugger. Something's not initialized, or maybe your `initializeQueue()` function is blowing it.  Try a binary-search, commenting out sections of code, until it stops blowing up..

Comment: So it turns out my count variable was not initialized and that the debugger(just learned how to use gdb yesterday!) helped me track it down. You guys are awesome, I wish i could give you reputation for those comments.